# How can i add icon images in Listview via Adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, icons

I have a sample code that i made for my custom navigation drawer. I don't know how can i add icons to every item position in the listview. The position indicates an intent in order to link the current page to another.I also put string items in an array named data so that i can add it via adapter. The listview is navList Please help!

```
public class HomePatient extends Activity {
final String[] data ={"Home","Health Progress","Diet","Workout","Medications","Help","Settings","Logout"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepatient);

final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptertext = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomePatient.this, R.layout.textholder, data);
    navList.setAdapter(adaptertext);

        navList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                String text = data[position];
                if(position==1)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomePatient.this, HealthProgress.class);
                    i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //onDestroy();
                    finish();
                }
                if(position==2)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomePatient.this, DietPatient.class);
                    i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //onDestroy();
                    finish();
                }
                if(position==3)
                {
                    //Intent i = new Intent(HomePatient.this, WorkoutPatient.class);
                    //i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                   // startActivity(i);
                    //onDestroy();
                    //finish();
                }
                if(position==4)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomePatient.this, TreatmentPatient.class);
                    i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                    startActivity(i);
                   // onDestroy();
                    finish();
                }
                if(position==7)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomePatient.this, PatientLogin.class);
                    i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //onDestroy();
                    finish();
                }

            }
});
```

Comment: r u using custom listview? if no u can achieve it with custom listview check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know how can i add icons to every item position in the
>   listview

Because you are using default [android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) layout which contain only one `TextView`. to show images and text both in `ListView` row you will need to create custom layout then pass it to ListView Adapter. see following example to create custom `ArrayAdapter`

[Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

Answer (score 2):

You have use baseadapter for that and use custom adapter and custom list row item

have a look at

http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/

Answer (score 2):

Use custom Listview with BaseAdapter.
Here is the [link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ka5Tk7J9rG0)

Answer (score 1):

```
/* here is my activity*/

public class abc extends Activity{

  public String[] items{
    "A","B"
   };

 public void oncreate(***)
 {
  .........
  .......
  Listview lv =(Listview)findviewbyid(R.id.listview); // reference to list view 

  Myadapter myadapter = new     Myadapter(this,android.r.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.r.id.text,items); 

lv.setadapter(myadapter); // i am setting my list view to this adapter
}


}


// here goes my adapter class



public class Myadapter extends Arrayadapter<String>

{
  Context context;
  String[] objs;

  public Myadapter(context context , resouce , txtresid , String[] objs)
 {
   super(context , resouce , txtresid , objs);
   this.context = context;
   this.objs= objs;
 }
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         // now i will inflate my xml by returning view
         // create an xml file that contais imageview and text or whatever you want 
         // i have named my xml file as simple_list.xml
            Layoutinflater inflater = (Layoutinflater)             context.getsystemservice(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     View view = inflater.inflater(R.layout.simple_list.xml,parent,false);//check out layout inflater class and its method 
      Imageview iv = (Imageview)view.findviewbyid(R.id.imgview);
      Textview tv  = (TextView) view.findviewbyid(R.id.txtview);


      tv.setText(objs[position]);

      if(objs[position].equals("A"))
      {
        iv.setimageresource(R.drawable.someimage);
      }
      else if(objs[position].equals("B"))
      {
         iv.setimageresource(R.drwable.nextimage);
      }    


        return view;
    }






}
```